# Cuda Mutex, why deadlock?

Tags: cuda

I am trying to implement a atomic based mutex.

I succeed it but I have one question about warps / deadlock.

This code works well.

```
bool blocked = true;

while(blocked) {
    if(0 == atomicCAS(&mLock, 0, 1)) {
        index = mSize++;

        doCriticJob();

        atomicExch(&mLock, 0);
        blocked = false;
    }
}
```

But this one doesn't...

```
while(true) {
    if(0 == atomicCAS(&mLock, 0, 1)) {
        index = mSize++;

        doCriticJob();

        atomicExch(&mLock, 0);
        break;
    }
}
```

I think it's a position of exiting loop. In the first one, exit happens where the condition is, in the second one it happens in the end of if, so the thread wait for other warps finish loop, but other threads wait the first thread as well... But I think I am wrong, so if you can explain me :).

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There are other questions here on mutexes.  You might want to look at some of them.  Search on "cuda critical section", for example.
2. Assuming that one will work and one won't because it seemed to work for your test case is dangerous.   Managing mutexes or critical sections, *especially when the negotiation is amongst threads in the same warp* is notoriously difficult and fragile.  The general advice is to avoid it.  As discussed elsewhere, if you must use mutexes or critical sections, have a single thread in the threadblock negotiate for any thread that needs it, then control behavior within the threadblock using intra-threadblock synchronization mechanisms, such as `__syncthreads()`.
3. This question (IMO) can't really be answered without looking at the way the compiler is ordering the various paths of execution. Therefore we need to look at the SASS code (the machine code).  You can use the [cuda binary utilities](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#abstract) to do this, and will probably want to refer to both the [PTX reference](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#abstract) as well as the [SASS reference](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#instruction-set-ref).  This also means that you need a *complete code*, not just the snippets you've provided.

Here's my code for analysis:

```
$ cat t830.cu
#include <stdio.h>


__device__ int mLock = 0;

__device__ void doCriticJob(){

}

__global__ void kernel1(){

  int index = 0;
  int mSize = 1;
  while(true) {
    if(0 == atomicCAS(&mLock, 0, 1)) {
        index = mSize++;

        doCriticJob();

        atomicExch(&mLock, 0);
        break;
    }
  }
}

__global__ void kernel2(){

  int index = 0;
  int mSize = 1;
  bool blocked = true;

  while(blocked) {
    if(0 == atomicCAS(&mLock, 0, 1)) {
        index = mSize++;

        doCriticJob();

        atomicExch(&mLock, 0);
        blocked = false;
    }
  }
}
int main(){

 kernel2<<<4,128>>>();
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

`kernel1` is my representation of your deadlock code, and `kernel2` is my representation of your "working" code.  When I compile this on linux under CUDA 7 and run on a cc2.0 device (Quadro5000), if I call `kernel1` the code will deadlock, and if I call `kernel2` (as is shown) it doesn't.

I use `cuobjdump -sass` to dump the machine code:

```
$ cuobjdump -sass ./t830

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_20
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_20

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_20
code version = [1,7]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_20
                Function : _Z7kernel1v
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM20 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM20)"
        /*0000*/         MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];            /* 0x2800440400005de4 */
        /*0008*/         MOV32I R4, 0x1;                   /* 0x1800000004011de2 */
        /*0010*/         SSY 0x48;                         /* 0x60000000c0000007 */
        /*0018*/         MOV R2, c[0xe][0x0];              /* 0x2800780000009de4 */
        /*0020*/         MOV R3, c[0xe][0x4];              /* 0x280078001000dde4 */
        /*0028*/         ATOM.E.CAS R0, [R2], RZ, R4;      /* 0x54080000002fdd25 */
        /*0030*/         ISETP.NE.AND P0, PT, R0, RZ, PT;  /* 0x1a8e0000fc01dc23 */
        /*0038*/     @P0 BRA 0x18;                         /* 0x4003ffff600001e7 */
        /*0040*/         NOP.S;                            /* 0x4000000000001df4 */
        /*0048*/         ATOM.E.EXCH RZ, [R2], RZ;         /* 0x547ff800002fdd05 */
        /*0050*/         EXIT;                             /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
                ............................


                Function : _Z7kernel2v
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM20 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM20)"
        /*0000*/         MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];            /* 0x2800440400005de4 */
        /*0008*/         MOV32I R0, 0x1;                   /* 0x1800000004001de2 */
        /*0010*/         MOV32I R3, 0x1;                   /* 0x180000000400dde2 */
        /*0018*/         MOV R4, c[0xe][0x0];              /* 0x2800780000011de4 */
        /*0020*/         MOV R5, c[0xe][0x4];              /* 0x2800780010015de4 */
        /*0028*/         ATOM.E.CAS R2, [R4], RZ, R3;      /* 0x54061000004fdd25 */
        /*0030*/         ISETP.NE.AND P1, PT, R2, RZ, PT;  /* 0x1a8e0000fc23dc23 */
        /*0038*/    @!P1 MOV R0, RZ;                       /* 0x28000000fc0025e4 */
        /*0040*/    @!P1 ATOM.E.EXCH RZ, [R4], RZ;         /* 0x547ff800004fe505 */
        /*0048*/         LOP.AND R2, R0, 0xff;             /* 0x6800c003fc009c03 */
        /*0050*/         I2I.S32.S16 R2, R2;               /* 0x1c00000008a09e84 */
        /*0058*/         ISETP.NE.AND P0, PT, R2, RZ, PT;  /* 0x1a8e0000fc21dc23 */
        /*0060*/     @P0 BRA 0x18;                         /* 0x4003fffec00001e7 */
        /*0068*/         EXIT;                             /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
                ............................



Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_20
code version = [4,2]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
$
```

Considering a single warp, with either code, all threads must acquire the lock (via `atomicCAS`) once, in order for the code to complete successfully.  With either code, only one thread in a warp can acquire the lock at any given time, and in order for other threads in the warp to (later) acquire the lock, *that thread must have an opportunity to release it* (via `atomicExch`).

The key difference between these realizations then, lies in how the compiler scheduled the `atomicExch` instruction *with respect to conditional branches*.

Let's consider the "deadlock" code (`kernel1`).  In this case, the `ATOM.E.EXCH` instruction does not occur until *after* the one (and only) conditional branch (`@P0 BRA 0x18;`) instruction.  A conditional branch in CUDA code represents a possible point of warp divergence, and execution after warp divergence is, to some degree, unspecified and up to the specifics of the machine.  But given this uncertainty, it's possible that the thread that acquired the lock will wait for the other threads to complete their branches, *before executing the `atomicExch` instruction*, which means that the other threads will not have a chance to acquire the lock, and we have deadlock.

If we then compare that to the "working" code, we see that once the `ATOM.E.CAS` instruction is issued, there are *no* conditional branches in between that point and the point at which the `ATOM.E.EXCH` instruction is issued, thus releasing the lock just acquired.  Since each thread that acquires the lock (via `ATOM.E.CAS`) will release it (via `ATOM.E.EXCH`) before any conditional branching occurs, there isn't any possibility (given this code realization) for the kind of deadlock witnessed previously (with `kernel1`) to occur.

(`@P0` is a form of *predication*, and you can read about it in the PTX reference [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#instruction-statements) to understand how it can lead to conditional branching.)

**NOTE:**  I consider both of these codes to be dangerous, and possibly flawed.  Even though the current tests don't seem to uncover a problem with the "working" code, I think it's possible that a future CUDA compiler might choose to schedule things differently, and break that code.  It's even possible that compiling for a different machine architecture might produce different code here.    I consider a mechanism like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963293/cuda-atomics-change-flag) to be more robust, which avoids intra-warp contention entirely.  Even such a mechanism, however, can lead to inter-threadblock deadlocks.  Any mutex must be used under specific programming and usage limitations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanations.

I saw your method, but I have a deadlock without volatile, volatile fix this deadlock? Or does it work only with a block with one only thread?

I need all threads here, because it's for photon tracing part :).

Thanks a lot :).

Comment: The method I describe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963293/cuda-atomics-change-flag) is only intended to be used by one thread per block **to acquire the lock**. It does not preclude the possibility of using multiple threads, once the lock is acquired by the threadblock.  Where it says "begin critical section here", all the threads will be participating at that point.  Again, if you want to have multiple threads in the same warp competing for locks, you're welcome to try it if you wish, but in my opinion that is difficult and possibly dangerous.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot in all cases :).
You help me to understand how to debug program a lot :). The next time I'l have problem, I will read assembly :).