# Cuda atomics and conditional branches

Tags: c++, algorithm, cuda, atomic, compare-and-swap

I am attempting to write a `CUDA` version of a `serial` code as a part of implementing a periodic boundary condition in a molecular dynamics algorithm. The idea is that a tiny fraction of particles that have positions out of the box need to be put back in using one of two `ways`, with a limit on number of times I use the first way.

Essentially, it boils down to the following MWE. I have an array `x[N]` where `N` is large, and the following `serial` code.

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  int N =30000;
  double x[30000];
  int Nmax = 10, count = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    x[i] = 1.0*(rand()%3);

  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
      if(x[i] > 2.9)
        {
          if(count < Nmax)
            {
              x[i] += 0.1; //first way
              count++;
            }
          else
            x[i] -= 0.2; //second way
        }
    }
}
```

Please assume that `x[i] > 2.9` only for a small fraction (about 12-15) of the 30000 elements of `x[i]`.

Note that the sequence of `i` is not important, i.e. it is not necessary to have the `10` lowest `i` to use `x[i] += 0.1`, making the algorithm potentially parallelizable. I thought of the following `CUDA` version of the MWE, which compiles with `nvcc -arch sm_35 main.cu`, where `main.cu` reads as

```
#include <cstdlib>

__global__ void PeriodicCondition(double *x, int *N, int *Nmax, int *count)
{
  int i = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
  if(i < N[0])
    {
      if(x[i] > 2.9)
        {
           if(count[0] < Nmax[0]) //===============(line a)
             {
               x[i] += 0.1; //first way
               atomicAdd(&count[0],1); //========(line b)
             }
           else
             x[i] -= 0.2; //second way
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
  int N = 30000;
  double x[30000];
  int Nmax = 10, count = 0;

  srand(128512);
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    x[i] = 1.0*(rand()%3);

  double *xD;
  cudaMalloc( (void**) &xD, N*sizeof(double) );
  cudaMemcpy( xD, &x, N*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

  int *countD;
  cudaMalloc( (void**) &countD, sizeof(int) );
  cudaMemcpy( countD, &count, sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

  int *ND;
  cudaMalloc( (void**) &ND, sizeof(int) );
  cudaMemcpy( ND, &N, sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

  int *NmaxD;
  cudaMalloc( (void**) &NmaxD, sizeof(int) );
  cudaMemcpy( NmaxD, &Nmax, sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

  PeriodicCondition<<<938,32>>>(xD, ND, NmaxD, countD);

  cudaFree(NmaxD);
  cudaFree(ND);
  cudaFree(countD);
  cudaFree(xD);

}
```

Of course, this is not correct because the `if` condition on `(line a)` uses a variable that is updated in `(line b)`, which might not be current. This is somewhat similar to [Cuda atomics change flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963293/cuda-atomics-change-flag), however, I am not sure if and how using critical sections would help.

Is there a way to make sure `count[0]` is up to date when every thread checks for the `if` condition on `(line a)`, without making the code too serial?

Comment: I think the answer by @Claude is a good one and is quite simple and tidy if you can tolerate `count[0]` being incremented always.  To reproduce the exact behavior of your serial code (`count` increments until it reaches `Nmax`, and then stops) it should be possible to use a custom atomic built around `atomicCAS`.  I suspect performance-wise it will be costlier than the answer by Claude, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just increment the atomic counter every time, and use its [return value](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicadd) in your test:

```
...
  if(x[i] > 2.9)
    {
       int oldCount = atomicAdd(&count[0],1);
       if(oldCount < Nmax[0])
         x[i] += 0.1; //first way
       else
         x[i] -= 0.2; //second way
    }
...
```

If as you say around 15 items exceed 2.9 and Nmax is around 10, there will be a small number of "extra" atomic operations, the overhead of which is probably minimal (and I can't see how to do it more efficiently, which isn't to say it isn't possible...).