# CUDA: release lock implemented by atomic operations

Tags: cuda, atomic, critical-section

GPU: Quadro RTX 4000

CUDA: 11.7

I have implemented a global lock by atomic operations like:

```cpp
__global__ void floatAddLockExch(float* addr, volatile int* lock) {
    bool goon = true;
    while (goon) {
        if (atomicCAS((int*)lock, 0, 1) == 0) {
            *addr += 1; //critical task

            int lockValue = atomicExch((int*)lock, 0);
            if (lockValue != 1) {
                printf("Error in <%d, %d> \n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
            }
//
//          *lock = 0;
//          __threadfence();

            goon = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Tested this kernel by <<<`1`, 1024>>>, the output(value of *addr) was `1024`; tested by <<<`2`, 1024>>>, the output was `1025`. There was `No` "Error..." output in both cases.

Helped by [Cuda atomics change flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963293/cuda-atomics-change-flag), I've implemented the kernel as:

```cpp
__global__ void floatAddLockFence(float* addr, volatile int* lock) {
    bool goon = true;
    while (goon) {
        if (atomicCAS((int*)lock, 0, 1) == 0) {
            *addr += 1; //critical task

//          int lockValue = atomicExch((int*)lock, 0);
//          if (lockValue != 1) {
//              printf("Error in <%d, %d> \n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
//          }

            *lock = 0;
            __threadfence();

            goon = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The output was `1024` in <<<`1`, 1024>>> case and `2048` in <<<`2`, 1024>>> case.

[The test code in gist](https://gist.github.com/fulltopic/37308230d9df5df6757ca9806c1a76d3)

It is supposed that atomic operation on global variable `lock` is atomic across all blocks, why `floatAddLockExch` failed in multi-block case? How `__threadfence()` solved the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the `__threadfence()` makes a difference is not due to the lock mechanism itself, but the effect on the handling of `*addr`.

The lock mechanism is working in the multiblock case in that it is still serializing thread updates to the `*addr` variable, but the `*addr` variable handling is being affected by L1 cache activity.  Threads within the same threadblock are guaranteed to have a consistent view of the L1 cache contents.  Threads across separate blocks are not, because those blocks may be located on separate SMs, and separate SMs also have separate L1 cache.

The `__threadfence()` makes this update of the `*addr` visible to all blocks.  You might also be able to witness the same effect if you used your first (failing) test, but changed the kernel prototype decoration of `float *addr` to `volatile float *addr`.  The `volatile` keyword generally causes [bypassing](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#volatile-qualifier) of the L1 cache.

CUDA has recently introduced a [libcu++](https://nvidia.github.io/libcudacxx/) library that emulates parts of the "standard" C++ libraries.

One of the functionalities available so far is [semaphores](https://nvidia.github.io/libcudacxx/extended_api/synchronization_primitives.html#semaphores).

The following can be a libcu++ method to achieve a "critical section":

```
$ cat t1941.cu
#include <cuda/semaphore>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
 
__device__ cuda::binary_semaphore<cuda::thread_scope_device> s(1);
 
__global__ void k(volatile int *d){
 
  s.acquire();
  int test = *d;
  printf("block: %d, thread: %d, test: %d\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x, test);
  test += 1;
  *d = test;
  __threadfence();
  s.release();
}
 
 
int main(){
 
  int *d;
  int h;
  cudaMalloc(&d, sizeof(d[0]));
  cudaMemset(d, 0, sizeof(d[0]));
  k<<<2,2>>>(d);
  cudaMemcpy(&h, d, sizeof(d[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  std::cout << "d = " << h << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t1941 t1941.cu -arch=sm_70
$ ./t1941
block: 0, thread: 0, test: 0
block: 0, thread: 1, test: 1
block: 1, thread: 0, test: 2
block: 1, thread: 1, test: 3
d = 4
$
```

A few notes on the above example.

- it will require a volta or newer device, be sure to compile for the architecture to match your GPU (cc7.0 or newer)
- it will require CUDA 11.3 or newer
- the dynamic initialization of the `__device__` variable only happens once, which is sufficient for this example.  If you intend to use the semaphore repeatedly, for perhaps several kernel launches, then it will be necessary to re-initialize the device variable, perhaps using `cudaMemcpyToSymbol()`.

Comment: Yes, `volatile float* addr` worked for `floatAddLockExch`. Thank you.